# filter rows on column values with string methods

Tags: python, pandas

Input df:

```
title                        desc
movie A                  It is a awesome movie with action
movie B                  Slow but intense movie.
```

I want to filter rows which contains the following keywords:

```
keys =  ["awesome", "action"]
```

Output DF:

```
title                        desc
movie A                  It is a awesome movie with action
```

Code:

```
index_list = []
for index,rows in df.iterrows():
   if any(x in rows["desc"].split(" ") for x in keys) == True:
       index_list.append(index)

df = df.loc[index_list]
```

Approach:

```
In each row, I am checking if any of the keywords are present after splitting the rows
```

This approach works fine, but I am interested to know if there is any one liner in pandas to achieve the same.

Example:

```
df.loc[df['column_name'].isin(some_values)]
```

Comment: Use `df.desc.str.contains('|'.join(keys))`

Answer (score 3):

Why yes, there is - [pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
idx = df['column_name'].str.contains("|".join(keys), regex=True)
df[idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick for you:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {'title':['movie A', 'movie B'], 'desc':['It is a awesome movie with action', 'Slow but intense movie.']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
                                desc    title
0  It is a awesome movie with action  movie A
1            Slow but intense movie.  movie B
>>> keys =  ["awesome", "action"]
>>> df[df['desc'].str.contains('|'.join(keys))]
                                desc    title
0  It is a awesome movie with action  movie A
```